# Can GuestEntries edit existing entries?

Tags: guest-entries, guest, plugin-guestentries

I'm trying to use `<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{entry.id}}">` on a GuestEntries form. However, instead of editing the entry with the set ID, it creates a new post.

Am I missing something? Or is this not possible with the GuestEntries plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. It currently only allows for creating new entries, not editing existing ones.

Comment: Well, good to know that I'm not crazy. Was banging my head against the keyboard for a little bit.

Any way for someone like me to modify it? I'm not very familiar with Craft plugin dev. Would creating a plugin & using `guestEntries.beforeSave` be the right direction to go?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is of use to you, and if you use it I would recommend ensuring that you use is with security in mind. But someone has forked the GuestEntries plugin to allow editing and deleting of entries.

https://github.com/ChaseGiunta/GuestEntries